# Can we do this with GCC's inline functions?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, inline

As far as I know inline functions are code substituted in the caller, which means that any code written in an inline function lives in the last function's stack frame. I happen to be in a situation where I need to allocate memory dynamically without using malloc. Is there a way, then, for me to allocate a variable-length array in an inline function, and have it persist when the function terminates---you know, since the stack isn't really unwinding.

Thanks!

EDIT:

What I have is a function called in signal handler context, activated by sigpoll. It attempts to read data from a tcp socket. The data it reads is organised into data structures we came up with; artificial "packets", if you will. There is no telling how much data is in the buffer, where the "packet" boundaries are, etc. It's called by a signal handler, so we can't use any dynamic memory allocators.

Comment: If you don't want to allocate on the thread's function stack frame ([alloca](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca)) or the process heap ([malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)) then what's left are pages directly ([mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)). Or: have your own global memory pool (heap or pages) and allocate from there. But perhaps you could give more context on what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You mean, have the array persist when the _inline_ function terminates but free when the outer function terminates?

Comment: Is there need for inlined functions, i.e. are they called from multiple places within the function? Could you pass an [alloca](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca)'ed buffer into the inline function?

Comment: I think the answer is no. The GCC manual doesn't address exactly your situation but it's pretty close: "Note that certain usages in a function definition can make it unsuitable for inline substitution. Among these usages are: variadic functions, use of alloca, use of variable-length data types (see Variable Length),...." https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: I don't think this will work. Even if it did by chance, it would be a very fragile way of coding. In the "calling" function, the compiler will be expecting to own its stack frame exclusively. Thus you can't avoid damage if it decides to use your carefully arranged buffer with the next instruction(s).

Comment: Note: signal handlers do not normally do I/O (hence, sockets), because I/O calls are not async signal safe.  Consider some kind of polling, select, whatever, not signal handlers for I/O.   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Answer (score -1):

Hmm.  This seems to be another aspect of what you want.  Call all the `alloca` function to allocate stack memory.  alloca()- allocated memory goes away when the function terminates.  It returns a pointer

See this for further information.  Also note that using alloca may cause some other issues, so it is not perfect.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html